# show keywords in a text using VStudio 2012 with c++

Tags: c++, keyword, getline

I have a problem with my program, which is used to segment a text file to display keywords and store them in another file,

---

assume that **"my_text.txt"** file contains all the words of my text, separated with a newline, and "empty_words.txt" file containing all the empty words like (to, they, as well, .. etc..), my problem is that i  want to compare the words of the two files to extract the words that are not empty(keywords).

---

when I run my program, it shows me only the first word repeated several times.

thanks so much for helping me to solve this problem
and this is a little code I wrote

---

```
string newContent;
string emptyWordsContent;
ifstream newText("my_text.txt",ios::in);
ifstream emptyWords("empty_words.txt", ios::in);
ofstream finalText("final_text.txt",ios::out);
 
 
while ( std::getline(newText, newContent)){
    while(std::getline(emptyWords, emptyWordsContent)){
        if(newContent!=emptyWordsContent){
            finalText<<newContent<<endl;
        }
    }
 
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "empty"? what are you expecting as output? Maybe a short example could help.

Comment: i mean stopwords like( A..Z,0..9,hello,you,maybe,than,many,with,...etc) all the words could not be keywords

Comment: so, when i tap hello mister yankee i am aminoo
the program returns: mister
                     yankee
                     aminoo